# I've added a UIScrollView to a UIView (my detail view), how to display content now?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

(In XCode 4 with Storyboards, app for iPhone)

My DetailView: a UIView filled with Labels and ImageViews to display details recieved through a segue when a cell was selected in the MainTableViewController. Now I've added a UIScrollView on this UIView because I want the Labels and ImageViews to be diplayed in a scroll view instead.

The only thing visible in DetailViewController now when I run the app, is a blank ScrollView. None of the content I've passed from the TableView is displayed, it's not getting the selectedObject. How can I display my content and be able to swipe through the cells with swipeDetectedLeft now after the UIScrollView was added? I would be happy if you could make example with my code.

DetailViewController.h:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *viewScroller; 
    //Added a ScrollView..
    }

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *detailsDataSource; 
//Recieved from the TableView to know the order of the sorted TableView cells, cells populated with a mutable array from a plist of dictionaries)

@property int detailIndex; 
//To know which cell selected (for swiping throug cells)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedObject; 
//Content of selected cell from tableview (for swiping through cells)

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *aLabel; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *anImageView; 
//to display content
```

DetailViewController.m:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize aLabel,anImageView;
@synthesize selectedObject;

@synthesize detailsDataSource, detailIndex;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[viewScroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[viewScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 700)];

//A customized Label for NavigationBar    
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 44)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.numberOfLines = 2;
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 14.0f];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text = [selectedObject valueForKey:@"Name"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
[label release];


aLabel.text = [selectedObject valueForKey:@"A Label"];
anImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[selectedWine valueForKey:@"An Image"]];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDetectedLeft:)];
leftGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftGesture];
}

- (void)swipeDetectedLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
if (detailIndex != [detailsDataSource count])
    detailIndex++;

aLabel.text = [[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] valueForKey:@"A Label"];
//Here follows ImageView and NavigationbBar Label for the swipe..
}
```

EDIT:

If I set aLabel.text = @"Test" then it works. So the UIScrollView isn't getting the selectedObject from:

MainTableViewController.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]) {

    NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    detailViewController.selectedObject = [sortedObjects objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];

    detailViewController.detailsDataSource = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:sortedObjects];
    detailViewController.detailIndex = selectedRowIndex.row;
}
}
```

Comment: It is highly discouraged to put a UITableView into a UIScrollView. Since UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, there will be undefined/unexpected behavior if you do put a UITableView in a UIScrollView.

Comment: @Scott There is no TableView in the ScrollView. The DetailViewController is a regular UIView with a ScrollView in it. This is about the values to fill the Labels and ImageViews in the DetailView (and control the swipeDetectedLeft method). These values are passed **from** a UITableViewController through a segue to fill the properties in DetailViewController.h.

Comment: Sorry, misread that. Maybe I just don't understand your question, but I see that your label and image view are IBOutlets. Are they actually hooked up to a label and image view in your storyboard? If so, are they IN the scroll view, and not UNDER the scroll view? If they are not hooked up in IB, then I think your problem is that you're never adding the label and image as subviews of the scroll view.

Comment: @Scott The outlets are connected to the labels in scrollview in storyboard. If a add a label "Label" in storyboard without any propery connected to this label, the label is displayed in app. The connected labels are not displayed, so it seems the problem may have to do with the properties in the .h or maybe in viewdidload where the labeltext is set? Somewhere there is a misconnection though..

Comment: What if you change `aLabel.text = [selectedObject valueForKey:@"A Label"];` to `aLabel.text = @"Test";`, just to make sure that `[selectedObject valueForKey:@"A Label"]` isn't returning nil or an empty string.

Comment: @Scott If I do, then "Test" is displayed. So the ScrollView doesn't get my selectedObject in other words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answer was very simple: I just had to remove the UIView from the scene in the storyboard and place the UIScrollView directly onto the DetailViewController scene instead.