# ScrollView Prevents labels from working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `DetailViewController` that was working fine. It has labels and a `textView`. I added a `scrollView` to allow the `textView` to move up when it was selected, but after I put the `scrollView` under the old labels, the labels no longer display the data. I have been using a storyboard to do the UI. I assumed that I could just drop the scrollview in and place labels on top, figuring it would work. It didn't.

Why is this?

UPDATE:

For those who need the code, here it is:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize comment;
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3f;
#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(RootBeer*)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    [self.view addSubview:];
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.rootBeerNameLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"rootBeerName"] description];
         self.rootBeerBrewerLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"rootBeerBrewer"] description];
         self.rootBeerLocationLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"rootBeerLocation"] description];
         self.rootBeerDescriptionLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"rootBeerDescription"] description];
         self.rootBeerDetailsLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"rootBeerDetails"] description];
        self.rootBeerNotes.text = self.detailItem.comments.rootBeerComment; 
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Saved!");

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Comments* com = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Comments" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    if(self.detailItem){
        //update current job
        [com setValue:self.rootBeerNotes.text forKey:@"rootBeerComment"];
        [com setValue:[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"rootBeerId"] forKey:@"rootBeerId"];
        [self.detailItem setValue:com forKey:@"comments"]; 

        NSError* error = nil;
        if(![context save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        NSLog(@"Saved!");

    }else{
        //create new job
        NSManagedObject *newJob = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Jobs" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        /*
        [newJob setValue:self.company.text forKey:@"company"];
        [newJob setValue:self.position.text forKey:@"position"];
        [newJob setValue:self.jobId.text forKey:@"jobId"];
        [newJob setValue:self.notes.text forKey:@"notes"];

        */
        NSError* error = nil;
        if(![context save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        NSLog(@"Saved!");
    }
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]){
        context=[delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

@end
```

Comment: Maybe you should show the code so we can understand it more

Comment: Not that it will help, but here you go...

Comment: Is it storyboard based?

Comment: It is @IsaiahTurner. I just added that to the OP. Sorry I didn't do it earlier.

Comment: Judging by your reputation I assume you know to drag the elements (in the storyboard panel editor on the left) into the scroll view element.

Comment: Yes, I know that... Lol... The problem is that when I had them on the original detail view, I cut them, inserted the scrollview, then pasted the labels back in, but the labels did not display the data and I'm wondering what else I have to do to get it to work.

Comment: If you drag them out of the scroll view they work correctly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30291/discussion-between-isaiah-turner-and-blaine)

Comment: Yes. When I take the scrollview out, and insert the labels and text view into the original view, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://ios.robertlinnemann.com/configure-a-uiscrollview-entirely-in-storyboard-with-interface-builder/ very simple tutorial, but might help.

Answer (score 0):

"Actually the answer was very simple: I just had to remove the UIView from the scene in the storyboard and place the UIScrollView directly onto the DetailViewController scene instead." -
@ingenspor

Credit goes to: [I've added a UIScrollView to a UIView (my detail view), how to display content now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550605/ive-added-a-uiscrollview-to-a-uiview-my-detail-view-how-to-display-content-n)